# How can I find which program is running on a specific tmux session?

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

On a remote machine, I have a tmux session with ID *selu*, and I am running a python program
`python test.py` that runs a C++ program `main.cpp` with different parameters several times. I want to learn the parameters of C++ program running at the moment in that session. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on the `run-shell` command. Here is an example of how to grep the current active process of the active pane.

```
 bind-key M-v run-shell 'T=$(tmux display -p "#{pane_tty}" | sed "s=/dev/=="); if pgrep -t$T "fzf|vim|elvish" &> /dev/null; then tmux send-key M-v; elif pgrep -t$T "gdb" &> /dev/null; then tmux send-key PageUp; else tmux copy-mode; fi'
```

You can also add `-t <your session>` to `run-shell` in order to specify the needed session.